# get currently selected cell's row and column number

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am using *gspread* which is a Python API for Google Sheets. I want to get the currently selected cell's row and column number which may or may not be empty.
How do I do that?

There is nothing in the documentation about this. Is there some other way to solve this problem in Python

Comment: Unfortunately, the active cell cannot be retrieved using Sheets API. Although this might not be what you want, the spreadsheet service of Google Apps Script can achieve it.

Comment: I want to use tensorflow with google sheets that's why I want it in python. I read about this function  `getCurrentCell()` which will give me the currently highlighted cell in Apps Script. But I am not sure if I could use tensotflow.js in Google Apps Script.

Comment: I am now trying to solve this problem by writing a Google Apps Script which would get the currently highlighted cell and will write the cell's column number and row number in the sheet itself(in a particular cell) and I will read the data  from that cell using the sheets api in Python.

Comment: But I have a question. How do I create a trigger which gets triggered when user selects(clicks on it or maybe uses arrow keys to navigate to some other cell) a new cell.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no such triggers for it. I'm really sorry for this situation. As a workaround, for example, how about using the checkbox? When the checkbox is pushed, the event trigger of OnEdit can be used.